# How does stringByReplacingCharactersInRange work in swift?

Tags: nsstring, swift

I have this code in objective-c:

```
[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```

try to convert to swift, like so:

```
textField.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
```

but compiler says, `Int is not identical to 'String.index'`

How should I modify expression?

I am using both objective-c / swift expressions in UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField!,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {
```

[image]

Comment: How are you defining `range`, in both cases?

Comment: Both have NSRange type

Comment: I get a different error message relating the range, and not the string, like on the other thread

Comment: The other thread is about the same problem (implementing `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`). Have you tried the solution (using `bridgeToObjectiveC`) ? That seems to work fine. Error messages might change between beta releases of the Swift compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bridgeToObjectiveC()`

```
textField.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
```

it will more clarify

```
var st = "abc"
str.bridgeToObjectiveC().stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(2,1), withString:"r")
```

Explicit casting can also be done to `NSString` and it not needs `bridgeToObjectiveC`

```
var st = "abc" as NSString
let abc = st.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(2, 3), withString: "abc")
```

Comment: I get the same error with NSMakeRange

Comment: have you `import Foundation`

Comment: I have tested and working fine without `import Foundation` also

Comment: I have added 'import Foundation' too, but still get the error

Comment: bridgeToObjectiveC() helps

Comment: How can i do the same without converting the String to NSString